# How do I use some sort of text throughout my application in a DataClass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I am trying to use integers and text throughout my application. I am doing so by using a DataClass, and I have gotten the integer to work. However, I am unsure about what to do in order to use text. I am pretty sure that using a UILabel is incorrect. I will show you what I am trying to do below:

**DataClass.h**

```
@interface DataClass : NSObject 
{    
    int i;
    UILabel *name;
} 

@property(nonatomic,assign)int i;    
@property(nonatomic,assign)UILabel *name;

+(DataClass*)getInstance;    

@end
```

**DataClass.m**

```
#import "DataClass.h"

@implementation DataClass    
@synthesize i, name;    
static DataClass *instance =nil;    
+(DataClass *)getInstance    
{    
    @synchronized(self)    
    {    
        if(instance==nil)    
        {    
            instance= [DataClass new];    
        }    
    }    
    return instance;    
}   

@end
```

**StarsViewController.m**

```
//I removed all unessential material for this question

#import "DataClass.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstanceAgain];  
    obj.name.text = @"PleaseWork";
    NSLog(@"%@", obj.name.text);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

In my NSLog, I am getting (null). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing the UILabel, well, as far as I can see. So you are sending the setText method to nil, which is valid but won't do anything.

Do you really need a UILabel to store text?

You can easily change the UILabel to an NSString, and change the property to:

```
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *name;
```

So you can set new text to it with:

```
DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstanceAgain];  
obj.name = @"PleaseWork";
```